# ag-grid custom details don't scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, frontend, ag-grid, styling

I noticed in my webpage that if I scroll the ag-Grid part of the screen horizontally, then the column header and rows move, but not the expanded details section which seems frozen/pinned in place. See images below, with attention to the bar at the bottom.The ag-Grid section scrolls vertically and moves with the master row like how you'd expect.

[GIF of scrolling demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yByO.gif)

[What you see upon loading and without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6mn6.png)

[After scrolling a bit to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGSdX.png)

What changes should I make, and where can I find the files that affect this? Is there a way to make the custom details cell pinned to the beginning (left) of the ag-Grid box?

I've tried changing the row width to span the whole thing, changing the div's position to align "none none", but it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dudung Hello, thanks for noticing my post. The code is owned by the company. In essence the rows upon rendering scroll with the grid, but the expanded section stays locked in place, unmoving and in the same position. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry that I can help you any further, @sheep14, since I can not access imgur.com at my place (an unsolved old problem), I hope someone notice your question and can answer it.

Comment: @dudung I ended up using  document.querySelector() and setting .addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const scrollLeft = gridContainer.scrollLeft; 
      detailContainer.style.transform = "translateX(-" + scrollLeft + "px)"; which works great.

Comment: I am glad that you can solved the problem, @sheep14. Btw, if you think that your solution worth to share, you can follow the guideline here https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
  detailScrolling() {
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport') as HTMLDivElement | null;
    const detailContainer = document.querySelector('.ag-full-width-container') as HTMLDivElement | null;

    detailContainer.style.width = '3000px'
    gridContainer.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      const scrollLeft = gridContainer.scrollLeft; 
      detailContainer.style.transform = "translateX(-" + scrollLeft + "px)";
    })
  }  ```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).